# Showing that $\varphi_{i_1}\otimes \dots \otimes \varphi_{i_k}$ is a basis for $J^k(V)$(Calculus on manifolds)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a vector space and $J^k(V)$ be the set of $k-\text{linear}$ maps from $V^k$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Also, let $\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$ and let $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n$ be the dual basis, $\varphi_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$. We need to show that  that $\varphi_{i_1}\otimes \dots \otimes \varphi_{i_k}, 1\leq i_1,\dots, i_k\leq n$ is a basis for $J^k(V)$.Spivak has shown that $\displaystyle\varphi_{i_1}\dots \otimes \varphi_{i_k}(v_{j_1},\dots,v_{j_k})=\delta_{i_1,j_1}\dots\delta_{i_k,j_k}$. Then he takes vectors $w_1,\dots, w_k$ with $w_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_j$ and for $\displaystyle T\in J^k(V)$ , $\displaystyle T(w_1,\dots,w_k)=\sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k=1}^na_{1,j_1}\dots a_{k,j_k}T(v_{j_1},\dots v_{j_k})$ and I understand till this point. But then he writes this down :

$\displaystyle \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k=1}^na_{1,j_1}\dots a_{k,j_k}T(v_{j_1},\dots v_{j_k})=\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k=1}^nT(v_{i_1},\dots, v_{i_k})\cdot \varphi_{i_1}\otimes\dots \otimes \varphi_{i_k}(w_1,\dots, w_k)$ and I don't understand this line at all.

I am probably getting bogged down by the notation but I don't know how that follows. Also, on a side note, how does one pronounce that that thing that looks like a J in $J^k(V)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace, in the line you don't understand on the right hand side, each $w_i$ by the expression $w_i= \sum_j a_{ij} v_j$. Then use mulitinearity and the $\delta_{ij}$ identity for the tensor product to get the left hand side.

Regarding the pronounciation question I cannot help you.